# is it possible to concat obj with string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have,

```
var output= "[1][2][3][4]"
```

and TMP is a object which one the the program understands it.

so I would like to have

```
tmp[1][2][3][4]= "value I send"
```

so, tmp +output becomes `tmp[1][2][3][4]`

I am really not sure. I searched but found only like EVAL.

this thing doesnt work below

```
var test = "tmp" + output

test=msg
```

only this works

```
tmp[A][B][C]=msg
```

any suggestions?

Comment: This makes little to no sense. Please explain what you are ultimately trying to achieve and what you have tried so far.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? `eval` is function which shouldn't be used and it is in JS, not Java

Comment: I'd considered to change the data to an array of numbers, though you can convert the string you have to a such as well.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you dealing with some undefined look at below code that works for me!

```
var output= "[1][2][3][4]";
var test = "tmp" + output;

var msg= "value I send";
test=msg;

console.log(test);
```